# how to check if a variable is a property

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

Suppose there is a class with a `@property` defined:

```
class MyClass:
   ...
   @property
   def this_is_a_property(self):
       return self.some_thing
   ...
   def this_is_a_function(self, x):
       ...
       return other_thing
```

Normally, to check whether an attribute is a function, I can use `isfunction` from the `inspect` module.

```
 import inspect
 if inspect.isfunction(MyClass.__dict__['this_is_a_function']):
    print('this_is_a_function',' is a function')
```

How can I check a `property`? There appears to be no `inspect.isproperty` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply check the type against the `property` object:

```
if isinstance(MyClass.this_is_a_property, property):
```

You don't really have to retrieve it from the class dictionary here; looking up a property on the class as an attribute also returns the `property` instance.

Comment: yes, though this is not a certain way to test this; the actual instance could be *another* descriptor that just returns a `property` when looked up on a class ;) (far-fetched yes)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`inspect.isdatadescriptor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isdatadescriptor):

> Return true if the object is a data descriptor. ... Examples are
>   properties (defined in Python), getsets, and members.
>
> ...
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** getsets are attributes defined in extension modules via PyGetSetDef structures.
>
> ...
>
> **CPython implementation detail:** Member descriptors are attributes defined in extension modules via PyMemberDef structures

Data descriptors are just types that have certain methods. See [3.3.2.1. Implementing Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors):

> If the descriptor defines `__set__()` and/or `__delete__()`, it is a data
>   descriptor; if it defines neither, it is a non-data descriptor.

Non-data descriptors include [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) and [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) (that is, they're not functions, they're *types*). For example, `inspect.isdatadescriptor(MyClass.this_is_a_classmethod)` would return `False`.

On the other hand, `property` *is* a data descriptor:

```
In [6]: inspect.isdatadescriptor(MyClass.this_is_a_property)
Out[6]: True
```

The downside of using this function is that it may return `True` if `isinstance(mystery, property)` is `False`.

A better way is to check for object type directly:

```
In [7]: isinstance(MyClass.this_is_a_property, property)
Out[7]: True
```

Comment: `property` is a *type* of data descriptor; any object with both `__get__`  and `__set__` methods would qualify; this includes attributes defined with `__slots__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, I updated my answer.